# Quartz.NET - how to detect whether a job is paused?

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm using Quartz.NET in a Windows Service I am creating, and I'd like a way to iterate over all jobs to detect whether it is paused or not. How do I check if a job is paused? I can't find a suitable method in the JobDetail class.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you check the trigger not the job itself.

```
if (scheduler.GetTriggerState(triggerName, triggerGroup) == TriggerState.Paused)
{
    //paused
}
```